# Windows Phone 8.0 - how to detect previously installed version of the application

Tags: windows-phone-8, installation, windows-phone, storage

Is there any way to detect previous version of the application after update?

Problematic scenario:
User installs an application but never launch it. After some time application is updated automatically or via Store application. Now user launch the application and how to check if update happend and what version was previously installed?

There is no problem if user launch the application before update. I could write something to Isloated Storage which survive update. But what about scenrio described above?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You simply store a version number alongside your Isolated Storage. It doesn't make a difference whether the user launches the app or not. If persisted information exists on application startup, and it is outdated, upgrade it version by version.

Comment: How to store app version in Isolated Storage without launching the application? Can I put some file to IS during installation?

Comment: The problem is that application installed first time must store its version somewhere / somehow even it won't be launched after installation.